# in UR5_Driver(Driver.py)--ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup

Tags: ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

This question is with reference to universal_robot package, I did a fresh installation of ROS Groovy on my Ubuntu PC(12.04) and also cloned the universal_robot stack from git-hub. followed all steps until catkin_make and sourcing setup.bash. The very first time I run this command

```
$ roslaunch ur_bringup ur5.launch robot_ip:=192.168.1.5
```

I get the below error, which is apparently a parser.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bucky/catkin_ws/src/universal_robot/ur_driver/src/ur_driver/driver.py", line 11, in <module>
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup
```

During the previous installations, I overcame the same problem by installing the file using

```
$ sudo easy_install BeautifulSoup
```

The Question is, which version of the file should I install, BeautifulSoup or BeautifulSoup4 and should I update the PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did anyone face the same issue when proceeding with this installation?

Thanks and Regards,
Murali

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103191/in-ur5_driver(driver.py)--importerror:-no-module-named-beautifulsoup/) by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 246 on 2013-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The beautiful soup package can be downloaded by the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-beautifulsoup
```

This should not require any additional updates to the PYTHONPATH variable.  It should just work from here.

As an aside, the universal robot package is also available for groovy using:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-universal-robot
```

By downloading the package using sudo apt-get, the dependencies like Beautiful Soup should be taken care of.  However, there are some features in the github groovy version that are not in the debian version.

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2013-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on 2013-11-21**:
Thank you Shaun, I was more concerned about the version of the beautiful soup package. This answer explains what I wanted ...